# How to open an application on a specific screen/display using JavaScript for Automation (JXA)?

Tags: macos, automation, applescript, javascript-automation

I would like to open two applications on two different screens/displays using [JavaScript for Automation (JXA)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/Articles/Introduction.html), how is it possible?

I'm able to open the applications, but I can't find a way to control where it should open.

Answer (score -1):

I use a key code methode for setting a particular space

```
se = Application('System Events');
function setSpace() {
    se.keyCode(18 ,{using : 'control down' });
}
```

this will focus on the first space